# How do I access Apple's AASA validator (App Search API Validation Tool)?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios-universal-links, apple-appclips, apple-app-site-association

When building an Apple App Site Association file (AASA or `apple-app-site-association` file), it's very easy to get it wrong. That's why Apple built a "**App Search API Validation Tool**" ([ref1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/67573), [ref2](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710161)).

This seemed to be available as recently as June 2022 at https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/. However, that site now redirects to a [generic page about universal links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/).

I would like to use Apple's tool to validate my AASA file because when I chose my build in App Store Connect, it shows that there are problems with my AASA file:

> [image]
>
> DOMAIN STATUS: 1 invalid domain

> [image]
>
> CACHE STATUS: Cannot Reach AASA File
>
> DEBUG STATUS: Invalid Entitlement: Unknown ID

How do I access Apple's App Search API Validation Tool?

---

I know there are 3rd party AASA validators:

- https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/
- https://yurl.chayev.com/

... however, these are not built by Apple, so may not be as thorough as Apple's tool. Case in point, my AASA file succeeds on both of these sites, even though it fails on App Store Connect.

Comment: One of the most useful tools is [sysdiagnose](https://www.wwt.com/article/using-sysdiagnose-on-ios-to-troubleshoot-universal-links) This lets you see what the device sees when it attempts to load the file.

Answer (score 37):

I can’t recall since when or why, but **as of April 2024** I have been using the following successfully:

```
https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/<domain>
```

e.g.

`https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/spotify.com`

Comment: what does it mean, if I get "Not Found" response, even though accessing the direct url from my domain shows the json file?

Comment: It means that Apple’s CDN has not been updated yet. It can take up to 24 hours I believe.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the troubleshooting steps we went through:

Check the Apple CDN by loading:

`https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/<domain>`

If the CDN cache has not updated yet (shows outdated file), then try to invalidate the cache by loading:

`https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/<domain>?timestamp=<current epoch time>`

(get the epoch time from here https://www.epochconverter.com) This may take a while to updated (> 8 hours for us)